# Aplicativo não funciona em determinado aparelho após compilado

Tags: android

Fiz um aplicativo, e no meu celular Lg g2, roda normal, mas em um samsung gran prime não roda. Diz que o aplicativo parou erro 41. O que pode ser?

```
Build.gradle:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "alfalarmes.hbzdev.com.alfalarmes"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Se tiver acesso ao dispositivo a melhor maneira de descobrir o problema seria debugando no mesmo.

Comment: Tire um log utilizando o logcat e nos envie por favor. Sem algo para analisar, fica dificil ajudar.

Comment: Segue o log, peguei as linhas em vermelho do log:
04-15 02:51:27.856 1039-1039/alfalarmes.hbzdev.com.alfalarmes E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.monkeyPatchExistingResources

04-15 02:51:27.884 1039-1039/alfalarmes.hbzdev.com.alfalarmes E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.pruneResourceCache
alfalarmes.hbzdev.com.alfalarmes.SplashActivity.access$super
tem outros error parecidos com esses acima... espero que ajude..

Comment: acho que esses erros abaixo podem ajudar mais:
04-15 00:17:10.575 13446-13446/alfalarmes.hbzdev.com.alfalarmes E/SysUtils: ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus

04-15 00:17:10.595 13446-13446/alfalarmes.hbzdev.com.alfalarmes E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY

04-15 00:17:10.640 13446-13446/alfalarmes.hbzdev.com.alfalarmes E/DataReductionProxySettingListener: No DRP key due to exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp

no meu lg g2 ta rodando normal....

Comment: Você poderia editar sua pergunta anexando a ela o seu arquivo **build. gradle(APP)**?

Answer (score 0):

Achei o erro e a solução!

> Erro: error: device unauthorized. This adbd's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set; try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong. Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.

Solução:
Como foi falado nesse [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31638582/2556111), apaguei a adbkey e compilei novamente... ae foi...