# Aplicativo não funciona após gerar .APK

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estou enfrentando um problema ao tentar gerar um apk de aplicativo desenvolvido no Android Studio. Após gerar o .apk para instalar o app em outros celulares, o aplicativo é instalado mas não abre.

Em celulares com android 9 ele apresenta o erro "Aplicativo apresenta falhas continuamente" e em outras versões do android ele apresenta o erro "O Aplicativo parou de funcionar".

O modo que uso para gerar o apk é: menu Build -> Generate Signed Bundle/APK... e sigo os passos de gerar chave, registrar etc. Já gerei outros aplicativos desta mesma forma e não tive nenhum problema. Para debugar o aplicativo eu utilizo tanto um aparelho físico (Android 8.0) quanto emuladores (versões do Android variados) e pelo menos deste modo o aplicativo não apresenta erros, nem na parte tela de Debug e nem no Logcat. Vou postar aqui como está o meu Manifest e Gradle.

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.wqueiroz.publictaxi">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity
            android:name=".UI.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".UI.UI.ScanActivity" />

        <activity android:name=".UI.UI.InformacoesViagemActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".UI.UI.PerfilActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".UI.UI.CreditosActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".UI.UI.LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".UI.UI.CadastroActivity"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.wqueiroz.publictaxi"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
        'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'

implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'}
```

Obs: Já procurei algumas resposta aqui no site para este problema:
[Aplicativo não funciona em determinado aparelho após compilado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123520/aplicativo-n%c3%a3o-funciona-em-determinado-aparelho-ap%c3%b3s-compilado)
e 
[Problemas para gerar APK em Android Studio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/197328/problemas-para-gerar-apk-em-android-studio), mas não resolveram minha situação.

Se alguém puder dar uma dica de como posso resolver esta situação desde já agradeço.

Comment: Você já tentou migrar o projeto para AndroidX? Se não me engano tem a documentação do próprio Google que estava instruindo todos os desenvolvedores a migrarem seus projetos pra versão mais atual do SDK se não me engano a targetSDK 28, pode também tentar migrar ele para o AndroidX, talvez resolva seu problema

Comment: @Q. Wesley, Já vi problemas desse tipo e se tratava de libs ausentes, talvez você esteja utilizando recursos que não está disponíveis para as versões que está testando, ou está havendo perda de libs durante o empacotamento.

Comment: Supondo que a aplicação esteja funcionando em modo debug (com o celular plugado no computador e executando no Android Studio), você tem de olhar com microscópio o logcat. Há diversos erros que são perdoados durante o modo debug mas não ao gerar um APK. Se não tiver nada suspeito, então tem de olhar o logcat da execução do APK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ou tu consegue um aparelho que apresente erro para ativar o modo desenvolvedor e usar o logcat para obter informações ou tu pode publicar o aplicativo na play store como uma versao de teste interno e cadastrar o email das pessoas que estao tendo problemas com o app para baixarem diretamente atraves do link que tu vai enviar.Dá um pouco de trabalho fazer isso mas desta forma o painel do desenvolvedor vai apontar o erro e em quais versoes do android ele ocorre.

outra coisa que voce pode fazer é ir em cada uma das activities e procurar por aquelas marcações em amarelo que são warnings.Essas mensagens apontam possiveis causadores de erros como nullpointerexception mas não impedem a compilação.As vezes os avisos apontados por esses marcadores nao causam erros em um primeiro momento mas depois começam a parar o app. Isso de ignorar esses avisos ja aconteceu comigo por isso deixo a sugestão.

Comment: Bom dia @juliano santos, eu agradeço por sua resposta, mas eu já estou fazendo exatamente isso. No caso eu testo esse aplicativo com um Moto Z2 com Android 9.0 com modo desenvolvedor ativo. Ao iniciar a aplicação o logcat não me apresenta nenhum erro, ele sobe normalmente. O que acho estranho é que em outros aparelhos (samsung A70 Android 9.0 por exemplo) quando instalo o apk ele roda a primeira vez, todas as activitys sem problema, porém, quando o aplicativo é fechado e reaberto ele apresenta os erros descritos no tópico.

Comment: alteirei a resposta. deixei mais duas sugestões.

Comment: agradeço muito suas dicas, após publicar uma versão de teste no google play e testar nos aparelhos que estavam com problema, acabei descobrindo o problema do meu aplicativo através do feedback dos teste realizados antes do lançamento, agora posso continuar meu desenvolvimento, muito obrigado.